# Java Swing, I am using a for loop in draw but only the last element is rendered on panel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Edited as an MRE. I wasn't really sure how to write the code without extending JFrame or JPanel. This will reproduce the same error I am seeing. I am trying to render bars on the JPanel, but it seems that only the last iteration of the for loop in the PlotPanel class is being drawn.

```
package com.company;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class VisualizeAlgorithms {
    public static int initPosX = 0;
    public static int initPosY = 0;
    public static int numBars = 200;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            PlotFrame frame = new PlotFrame();

        });
    }
}

class PlotFrame extends JFrame {
    PlotPanel plotPanel;
    PlotFrame() {
        plotPanel = new PlotPanel();
        this.add(plotPanel);
        this.setTitle("Plot");
        this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public int[] createArray(int numBars) {
        int[] numsArray = new int[numBars];
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            numsArray[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return numsArray;
    }

}

class PlotPanel extends JPanel{

    static final int PLOT_WIDTH = 1200;
    static final int PLOT_HEIGHT = 800;
    static final int MAX_BAR_HEIGHT = PLOT_HEIGHT;
    static final int BAR_WIDTH = PLOT_WIDTH / VisualizeAlgorithms.numBars;

    Dimension plotSize = new Dimension(PLOT_WIDTH, PLOT_HEIGHT);

    PlotPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(plotSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        int numBars = VisualizeAlgorithms.numBars;
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            g.fillRect(BAR_WIDTH * i, VisualizeAlgorithms.initPosY, BAR_WIDTH, ((i+1)/numBars)*(MAX_BAR_HEIGHT));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `VisualizeAlgorithms` is not defined. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. That MRE should not extend a frame, should include the `main` method into the class which makes the frame (to reduce the total number of classes), and demote the `PlotPanel` from public to default access so it can be included under the class with `main` allowing a single copy/paste. Add imports as well. Then copy that code to a new project to check it compiles without a single change and runs to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Printout `(i+1)/numBars)*(MAX_BAR_HEIGHT)` it may have values other than what you expect.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the clarifications on making a post that's easier to work with.

Comment: *"I wasn't really sure how to write the code without extending JFrame or JPanel."* Cool. Actually extending `JPanel` **is** necessary when custom painting as done in this code, as it is changing the behaviour of the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. Not so much frame, but we can look into that later. Otherwise, it's a great MRE! Short and to the point, and demonstrates the failure. Now I'm doing some basic debugging and I have to say I'm deeply confused as to what is going wrong. Will work more on it over the day, but perhaps @c0der can do some testing in the meantime.

Comment: Aside: @c0der gave great advice re "when in doubt, print out". I recommend using this change: `public void draw(Graphics g){
        int numBars = VisualizeAlgorithms.numBars;
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            int x = BAR_WIDTH * i;
            int y = VisualizeAlgorithms.initPosY;
            int w = BAR_WIDTH;
            int h = ((i+1)/numBars)*(MAX_BAR_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println(String.format("x,y WxH: %1s,%1s %1sx%1s", x,y,w,h));
            g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        }
    }` (print the values used for `fillRect`)

Comment: So to clarify, you are expecting to see something more [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC6SQ.png)? Note that I reduced it from 200 bars to just 10. If so, change the height to `int h = ((i+1)*MAX_BAR_HEIGHT/numBars);`

Comment: Got it, thanks both for the help

Comment: *"thanks both for the help"* Cool. Does that mean you solved the problem?

Comment: See [here](https://ideone.com/k98sSe) a version of your code that does not extend `JFrame` (and includes the changes suggested by @AndrewThompson)

Comment: @c0der Could you post that as an answer? I'd like to upvote it. PS: if it had not been for your comment, I'd still be looking closely at the `x` value passed to `fillRect`, so I think you are the major contributor to the solution.

Comment: @c0der One suggestion though. `frame.setResizable(false);` might cause the frame decorations to change in size. The borders are slightly larger on Windows (at least) to allow dragging the frame bigger & smaller. Thus it should be called *before* `pack()`. But a definite 'nice one!' on showing how to use a plain frame instance.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you. It is very kind of you. I'll leave it as a comment because it is really only a small contribution to help the OP to solve it by himself. I did move the  `setResizable` as you suggested (as well as `setVisible` to the end where it belongs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I can accept comments as answers, so I posted the answer here. It was indeed changing the rectangle height to `int h = ((i+1)*MAX_BAR_HEIGHT/numBars)`. Thanks both to @AndrewThompson and @c0der not only for the answer but the additional information as well.

Aside: @c0der gave great advice re "when in doubt, print out". I recommend using this change:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
     int numBars = VisualizeAlgorithms.numBars;
     for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
         int x = BAR_WIDTH * I;
         int y = VisualizeAlgorithms.initPosY;
         int w = BAR_WIDTH;
         int h = ((i+1)/numBars)*(MAX_BAR_HEIGHT);
         System.out.println(String.format("x,y WxH: %1s,%1s %1sx%1s", x,y,w,h));
         g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
     }
 }
```

(print the values used for fillRect)